# MPL Sample application

Tags: ios, paypal, sample

I am trying to integrate paypal in my iOS application for selling physical goods but having a really hard time in finding a sample application that makes use of MPL payment. Until now i have been following "https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/how-to-guides/how-accept-payments-ios-app-using-mpl" but it is pretty confusing regarding the fact that it does not provide complete format of the request. I have created 2 accounts - one who pays and another api caller account. I am really struck how to proceed ahead.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the samples are bundles in the MPL zip file that you might have already downloaded from here: [PayPal SDK Index](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-sdk-index?qt-paypal_sdk_index=2#qt-paypal_sdk_index). Once you unzip the file, you will find a SimpleDemo with the working code. Look in "FourButtonViewController.m" for more details.

Comment: Thanks for providing your valuable inputs. It did help (i ignored the file initially coz of lot of files in the demo app). However, i am still not sure how many accounts need to be created 2 or 3?

Comment: you just need a seller account to act as the receiver of the payment and a buyer account to act as the sender of the payment. For MPL you don't need API credentials. All you would need is the AppID - which is same for all in sandbox env and hardcoded in the sample too. That's pretty much what you need.

Comment: @Praveen Thank You! I've been looking everywhere for that info